# sample from a mixture

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, sampling, mixture-distribution

Suppose I have two types of students, male or female. Suppose a test score of a male student follows a distribution $F_m$ and suppose a test score of a female students follows a distribution $F_f$. Suppose there are equal number of male students and female students. Then can I say that, suppose there are sufficiently many male and female students, then a random sample from these students is iid from the mixure distribution of $0.5\cdot F_m+0.5\cdot F_f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the sampling is random it's a sample from a mixture distribution.

Consider the unconditional probabilities in terms of conditional probabilities -- this is just the [*law of total probability*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):

$P(X=x)=P(X=x|M)P(M)+P(X=x|F)P(F)$

(I use the discrete case here because test scores are discrete)

Here $P(M)=0.5$ and $P(F) =0.5$ and $P(X=x|M)$ is just the conditional probability function of test scores for males (etc).

Or in terms of distribution functions, we again apply the law of total probability:

$P(X\leq x)=P(X\leq x|M)P(M)+P(X\leq x|F)P(F)$

and so reproduce the proposed result in your question...

$=F_m\times 0.5+F_f\times 0.5$

Comment: does it work with sampling with replacements?

Comment: I assumed you were asking about sampling with replacement. If you weren't the answer doesn't apply (though if the sample is small relative to the population it hardly makes any difference). If the sample is a substantial fraction of the population then P(F) and P(M) are not constant as you go through drawing your sample (the mean is unaffected, but the variance is).